# Стандарт C++ на русском языке

Tags: стандарт, c++, c++11

Еще один вопрос по C++ - можно ли где-то найти стандарт этого языка, переведенный на русский? Читать полторы тысячи страниц (или сколько их там) на английском, к тому же имея немалую вероятность многое неверно истолковать и перевести - мне это пока что не под силу((

Comment: Наверное нет, плюс весь стандарт стоит читать только разработчикам компиляторов. Вам зачем?

Comment: Возможно будет полезно сравнение С++03 и С++11, это даст представление о том что изменилось без необходимости вычитывать весь стандарт, там нет описания на русском, но все же это проще понять что добавилось:
http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/c11-a-cheat-sheet-alex-sinyakov

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Нет. Учите английский.

Comment: английский и ещё раз английский. В моей практике был случай, когда читая переведенный ман (man select), я никак  не могу понять происходящее. А все было из-за того, что переводчик перевел неверно в `is the maximum number of file description` (в русском варианте было "максимальное количество дескрипторов", а нужно было бы "максимальный номер дескриптора". После того, как я прочитал фразу в английском варианте, на следующий день исправил баг, который тянулся в коде несколько лет.


Так что, свой язык забывать не стоит, а английский учить.

Comment: Но, вообще-то, стандарт С++ написан так, что и по-русски иногда без 100 гр. не разберешь )))

Comment: м, думаю, для некоторых людей перевод на русский не поможет. Это все равно, что если бы имел перевод японских иероглифов на русский, а не английский и это даст возможность сразу понимать японский.

Comment: @KoVadim вообще-то с переводом ошибка достаточно грубая, бо file description -- в единственном числе...

Comment: возможно я не совсем правильно процитировал. Но суть постарался передать. Потом обнаружилось, что в некоторых английских вариантах манов также есть ошибка (я тогда выверял маны во всех доступных дистрибутивах). В некоторых манах вместо слова number было count.

Comment: А у меня в RHEL (просто сейчас он под рукой)

    nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.

что инуитивно становится ясно  при взгляде на код макросов, манипулирующих наборами дескрипторов (но здорово вводит в заблуждение для винды, где все это сделано не так, а FD_CLR(), FD_SET() и т.д. это функции, интерфейс с poll()).

Comment: @avp у Винды этот аргумент у select() просто неиспользовался вообще, по крайней мере раньше. Но в  старой оффлайн документации была пометка что он зачит на Линукс. В онлайн документации этой строки не было.

Answer (score 10):

Есть, Зуев Е. А., Чупринов А. А. "Стандарт С++: перевод, комментарии, примеры". Приобрести можно далеко не везде, цена тоже не слишком радует (от 3к). Если говорить о качестве перевода, то оно вполне достойное, сам автор оставил много комментариев.

Comment: Ого, круто. Скину в чат по C++.

Comment: @Abyx да, так и есть, это перевод черновика, причем не всех глав (первые 18, кажется), и да, Вы правы, все же лучше читать на английском: так и язык подтянешь и привыкнешь к англоязычным терминам (некоторые вызывают трудности при переводе). Хотя, как я уже сказал, перевод достойный, вполне читабельный, да и читать в бумажном варианте приятнее.