# Где взять стандарт C++?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Многие ответы ссылаются на стандарт С++, а где его взять?

---

> Этот вопрос входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Стандарт С++ называется *International Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2020(E) – Programming Language C++*.

Число после двоеточия - год издания, предыдущие стандарты были в 2017, 2014, 2011, 2003 и 1998 годах.

### Официальное издание стандарта

Официальное издание стандарта публикуется ISO и стоит денег ([почему?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2734884/6944845)). Его можно [купить здесь](https://www.iso.org/standard/79358.html).

Также почитать/скачать можно [здесь](https://www.snti.ru/snips_iso.htm).

### Черновики стандарта

На сайте *open-std.org* публикуются [рабочие документы](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers) комитета про стандартизации, в том числе и черновики стандарта.
Когда очередная версия стандарта готова, публикуется "финальный черновик" (Final Draft), который затем отправляется в ISO. Он практически ничем не отличается от официального издания стандарта. Однако после публикации официального издания доступ к финальному черновику закрывается.

#### PDF файл рабочего черновика

Последняя опубликованная версия черновика - [N4868](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4868.pdf) от 2020-10-18.

#### Репозиторий GitHub

"Исходники стандарта" размещены на GitHub - https://github.com/cplusplus/draft. Их можно скомпилировать в .pdf и получить самый свежий черновик.

#### Финальные черновики

В [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/343443) на английском StackOverflow есть обновляемый список черновиков стандарта. Доступ к финальным черновикам закрыт, но их можно найти в интернете по их номерам.

Версии черновиков близких к официальным изданиям стандарта:

- C++17: [N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)
- C++14: [N3936](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf), N3937, N4141
- C++11: [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), N3291, [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)
- C++03: N1577, N1655, N1733

---

Также, постоянно обновляемый черновик стандарта в виде HTML можно найти [здесь](http://eel.is/c++draft) и [здесь](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp). HTML версии предыдущих черновиков:

- [C++11 (N3337)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337)
- [C++14 (N4140)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140)
- [C++17 (N4659)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659)
- [C++20 (N4868)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868)

Comment: А на русском стандарта не существует?

Comment: очень жаль что нет на русском. Чем больше занимаешься программированием, тем больше понимаешь, что математика для этого ремесла желательна но вовсе не обязательна - а английский обязателен.

Comment: @Nik ознакомьтесь с [вариантом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591832/176217).

Comment: Если у вас на работе покупают книги по программированию, то в рамках этих закупок можно попросить купить стандарт. Я на прошлой работе так и сделал.

Comment: @AndreyEpifantsev "весь стандарт стоит читать только разработчикам компиляторов. Вам зачем?"

Comment: @Alex78191 Приобретать его не обязательно для того, чтобы прочитать от корки до корки. Часто возникает необходимость разобраться в нюансах языка и поведения компилятора в конкретной ситуации, понять как должно быть правильно. Стандарт в этом случае является последней инстанцией. Опять же на форумах можно цитаты из стандарта в свои ответы вставлять.

Answer (score 13):

В конце 2016 вышел долгожданный перевод "Стандарт С++: перевод, комментарии, примеры" под редакцией Евгения Зуева и А.А. Чупринова. ISBN: 978-5-99079-159-6