# Подробности работы компилятора и линкера

Tags: c++, компоновщик

Рассмотрим следующий пример:

```
// file header1.h
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Foo" << '\n';
}

//  file source1.cpp
#include "header1.h"


//  file main.cpp
#include "header1.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

В связи с тем, что определение `foo` находится в хедере (что не очень хорошо), который включён в более чем один .cpp файл, линкер честно выдает ошибку наподобие:

> ```
> multiple definition of foo ... first defined in main.o ...
> ```

Одно из решений - сделать `foo` статической функцией, что обеспечит одно определение в объектных файлах:

```
static foo() { ... }
```

второе:

```
inline foo() { ... }
```

третье:

```
static inline foo() { ... }
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему `inline` функция тоже решает эту проблему?
2. Какие принципиальные отличия у этих решений?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с ответами и комментариями к вопросу [В каком случае нужно определять функцию в заголовочном файле?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429903/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5) — там разобраны все случаи и взаимодействие между файлами.

Answer (score 6):

1. `inline` решает эту проблему потому, что спецификация языка этого требует. Правило Одного Определения (One Definition Rule) для `inline` функций ясно говорит, что `inline` функция с внешним связыванием может определяться в программе много раз в разных единицах трансляции (точнее: *должна* определяться везде,  где одна используется и везде - одинаково).

   А уж как компиляторы/линкеры реализуют это требование - это их проблемы. Фактически, если такая функция породила тело в нескольких объектных файлах (т.е. не все ее вызовы заинлайнились), то линкеру будет предписано не ругаться на тему "multiple definition", а молча выбрать одно-единственное тело и остальные выбросить.

   Так как "классический" формат объектного файла не позволяет определить, где начинается и где заканчивается тело конкретной функции, для целей возможного будущего удаления компилятор их обычно помещает в выделенные секции объектного файла.
2. Принципиальное отличие между `inline` и `static` вариантом заключается в том, что `inline` функция сохраняет *внешнее связывание* (external linkage) и ведет себя во всех отношениях как функция со внешним связыванием. Например, если разные единицы трансляции попробуют взять адрес `inline` функции, то везде обязательно должно получиться одно и то же значение. Статические переменные, определенные внутри такой `inline` функции тоже существуют в единственном экземпляре во всей программе, как и в любой другой функции со внешним связыванием.

   В `static` варианте наоборот, функция получает *внутреннее связывание* (internal linkage) - каждая единица трансляции получает свою копию функции со своим уникальным адресом.

   Принципиальных отличий между `static inline` и `static` нет, с той только разницей, что в первом случае дается подсказка компилятору.

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить про статические переменные внутри `static` функции для сравнения с оными в `inline` функции.

Answer (score 3):

1. это очевидно из самой сути `inline` -- если код такой функции в самом деле "заинлайнен", то на него существует (логически) только одна ссылка (а именно в том месте, где код "инлайнится"), следовательно никаких проблем с "multiple definition" (т.е. проблемы выбора той или иной точки входа) не существует.
2. тут принципиальное отличие возникает при наличии `static` переменных у таких (`inline` и `static inline` функций. В каждой единице компиляции у `static inline` будут свои экземпляры таких переменных (а у "не static" один экземпляр `static` переменной 
   на весь загрузочный модуль (результат линковки)).

Comment: Насколько я помню, `inline` означает не «подставлять тело функции вместо вызова», а «игнорировать one definition rule».

Comment: @VladD в целом, inline-функция должна вставляться в код целиком, вместо кода ее вызова...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Согласно стандарту, не должна: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#2

Comment: Ну то есть не обязательно должна.