# В каких случаях компиляторы оптимизируют код?

Tags: c++

1. Вопрос про инициализацию стандартных типов. Например:

   ```
   float fl_val;
   fl_val = 1.0f;
   fl_val = 1.0;
   fl_val = 1;
   ```

   Здесь мы инициализируем `float` разными значениями. Понимают ли сейчас компиляторы (например, GCC и Visual Studio), что происходит, и оптимизируют эти моменты? Например, сразу приводят к `float` на этапе компиляции, а не во время выполнения: сначала `int(1)` приводят к `(1.0f)`. Затраты небольшие, но есть.
2. Вопрос с условием такого типа:

   ```
   int a; // пусть она инициализирована неизвестным значением
   int b = a >= 0 ? 1 : 2 * 10;
   ```

   `* 10` относится только к условию `false`, или к `true` тоже? Проверить сейчас возможности нет.

Comment: Если у вас несколько вопросов - задайте их отдельными вопросами. Не нужно собирать их в одном вопросе.

Comment: @Regent, прошу прощения, не сразу разобрался, в дальнейшем буду разделять вопросы

Comment: @Regent, ну **такие вопросы** пусть уж лучше пойдут одной простыней.

Comment: @avp да, у меня такая же мысль возникала. Конкретно в этом вопросе второй вопрос можно вообще убрать, так как он из серии "так возьмите и попробуйте". Собственно, на это я и рассчитывал.

Comment: @Regent, ага. А по второму вопросу я ему уже посоветовал (в комментарии к ответу @VladD) не экономить на скобках.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Да, компиляторы уже давно очень-очень умные в плане оптимизации. Они прекрасно оптимизируют все константы, до которых могут дотянуться. Вот вам [пример с gcc](https://goo.gl/FGTrzU): вот такая функция

```
#include <cstdio>

void f()
{
    float f = 4;
    printf("%f", f);
}
```

компилируется в следующее:

```
.LC1:
    .string "%f"
f():
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    .LC0(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    cvtss2sd    -4(%rbp), %xmm0
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    call    printf
    leave
    ret
.LC0:
    .long   1082130432
```

Вы видите созданную константу `.LC0 = 1082130432`. Это есть битовое представление `4.0f`, в чём легко [убедиться](http://ideone.com/bVfch9): вот такой код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    union { int32_t l; float f; };
    f = 4;
    cout << l;
    return 0;
}
```

выдаёт в точности 1082130432.

2) Ну это же легко проверить, есть гора онлайн-компиляторов. Например: http://ideone.com/GJHdaH выдаёт ответ 1, то есть, умножение имеет более высокий приоритет.

```
int a = 1;
int b = a >= 0 ? 1 : 2 * 10; 
cout << b;
```

Вы можете подсмотреть приоритеты в [стандарте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417798/10105) или в документации вашего компилятора, но для обычных целей простого эксперимента достаточно: вряд ли в имплементации компилятора *такая* дыра!

Важное «но»: если у вас возникли вопросы, такие же вопросы возникнут и у читателей вашего кода. Поэтому не поленитесь расставить скобки, чтобы смысл вашего кода не вызывал вопросов. Не надейтесь, что все остальные держат в голове таблицу приоритетов операций, тем более что в разных языках она разная. Для хорошего, долгоживущего кода очень важна читаемость.

Comment: Низкий поклон за подробное объяснение :)

Comment: @АлексейД, просто не экономьте скобочки (их мировой запас неограничен).

Comment: @АлексейД: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Отвечая по поводу оптимизации - да, понимают. Все-таки, в 21 веке живем, такие мелочи компиляторы должны на раз щелкать.

Вот такой код:

```
float fl_val;
fl_val = 1.0f;
fl_val = 1.0;
fl_val = 1;
```

Сlang++ преобразовал в следующий (на `-O0`, на `-O3`, разумеется, весь этот мусор отсутствует):

```
.LCPI1_0:
    .long   1065353216              # float 1
    .text
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
.Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp5:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Ltmp6:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movss   .LCPI1_0, %xmm0           # Загрузили 1 в регистр
    movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)           # fl_val = 1.0f;
    movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)           # fl_val = 1.0;
    movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)           # fl_val = 1;
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Как видим, в коде это одна и та же констатна, расположенная по адресу `.LCPI1_0`.

Введение новой константы ничего интересного не дает:

```
float fl_val;
fl_val = 1.0f;
fl_val = 1.0;
fl_val = 42;
```

Легким движением байтов, данный код превращается в элегантные <strike>шорты</strike> `long`-и:

```
.LCPI1_0:
    .long   1109917696              # float 42
.LCPI1_1:
    .long   1065353216              # float 1
    .text
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
.Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp5:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Ltmp6:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movss   .LCPI1_0, %xmm0         # Загрузили 42 в регистр
    movss   .LCPI1_1, %xmm1         # Загрузили 1 в регистр
    movss   %xmm1, -4(%rbp)         # fl_val = 1.0f;
    movss   %xmm1, -4(%rbp)         # fl_val = 1.0;
    movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)         # fl_val = 42;
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Comment: в элегантные лонги!

Comment: @VladD, Fixed! (еще один символ, да-да)