# Умные указатели (unique_ptr) и вызов функций-членов класса

Tags: c++, указатели

Собственно, ковыряю то, что написано в теме вопроса. Проблема возникла, когда я намеренно написал косячный код, а он, блин не упал.

Собственно, код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct cdmem {
    cdmem()             { std::cout << this << " :: cdmem::cdmem()"             << std::endl; };
    cdmem(const cdmem&) { std::cout << this << " :: cdmem::cdmem(const cdmem&)" << std::endl; };
    cdmem(const cdmem*) { std::cout << this << " :: cdmem::cdmem(const cdmem*)" << std::endl; };

    void testf()        { std::cout << this << " :: testf()"                    << std::endl; };

    ~cdmem()            { std::cout << this << " :: cdmem::~cdmem()"            << std::endl; };
};


int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<cdmem> pd(new cdmem);
    if(!pd) {
        std::cout << "\n ERR1 " << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    pd->testf();
    auto pd1(std::move(pd));
    pd->testf(); // Вот тут указатель уже нулевой
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
0x801c06058 :: cdmem::cdmem()
0x801c06058 :: testf()
0x0 :: testf() // this равен 0x0
0x801c06058 :: cdmem::~cdmem()
```

Получается, что обращения к самому объекту не происходит?

Comment: Ну, разыменование нулевого указателя — это UB, никто ничего не гарантирует, в том числе и падения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это классическое UB, (обращение к более невалидному указателю), которое в данном случае выражается в нормальной работе. Это частный случай, который в другой ситуации (навскидку - виртуальный метод и вырубленная оптимизация) выстрелит вам в ногу. Не делайте так.

Comment: Не могли бы вы предоставить ссылку из Стандарта, подтверждающую, что такой вызов функции ведет к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: Я могу разве что отправить http://habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/250701 в блог PVS Studio на Хабре, где есть пара огромных статей с разъяснениями UB при заигрываниях с невалидными указателями. Разыменовывать невалидный указатель точно запрещено. Оператор "стрелка", по сути, разыменовывает указатель. Вывод - UB.

Comment: Меня статьи не интересуют. Статьи - это не стандарт. Это всего лишь частная точка зрения на стандарт.  Меня интересует именно этот конкретный случай с точки зрения стандарта.

Comment: Та статья является как раз результатом глубокой проработки Стандарта (в ней есть ссылки на нужные пункты и переводы) и общения с экспертами.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: В последнем драфте (N4527), 20.8.1.2.4/3 ([unique.ptr.single.observers]): `pointer operator->() const noexcept;` _requires:_ `get() != nullptr`. Ссылка на драфт [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417798/10105).

Comment: @VladD Это требование относится к классу std::unique_ptr. А меня интересует вообще конструкция ptr->func(), где ptr - это nullptr, когда внутри функции нет обращения к членам класса, как в данном вопросе.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Ну, приведённый текст _уже_ гарантирует UB, без ссылок на разыменование nullptr. А по поводу разыменования nullptr сейчас поищу.

Comment: @VladD Проблема в том, что в C выражение *ptr, где ptr - это null указатель, является, похоже, корректным, так как там написано, что "If an
invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.102)", но NULL указатель является валидным значением,, о чем говорится в другом месте.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Я не сообразил сам, но мне кажется убедительным [это объяснение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2474021/276994).

Answer (score 3):

Тут играет роль неопределённое поведение.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void foo() { std::cout << "A::foo()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A * a = nullptr;
    a->foo();
}
```

Вывод:

> A::foo()

Это работает в MinGW 5.1.0, но далеко не факт что это будет работать в других версиях и в других компиляторах.

Comment: А также с этим компилятором с другими опциями компиляции. А также с этим компилятором, если вы вызовете эту функцию ещё откуда-то. А также с этим компилятором, если вы немного измените код, и оптимизатор соптимизирует чуть-чуть по-другому.

Comment: Даже оптимизация -O0 (компилировал clang++36) не уронила код в исходном виде. Падать начало только когда добавил дополнительный член (int) в структуру с явным обращением к нему.

Comment: @VladD, теоретически - да. Но мне не удавалось воспроизвести такую ситуацию. Видимо это особенность GCC.

Comment: @Nex, это логично, ведь его нет по адресу 0.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов: Это скорее особенности слишком простого кода. Для более сложного кода оптимизатор может найти другую возможность для оптимизации. Оптимизаторы становятся всё умнее и умнее, и активно используют UB для упрощения кода. Вот классическая статья по этому поводу: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213. И ещё: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: @VladD, возможно. Спасибо за статью.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо за статьи.

Comment: Пожалуйста! UB, как оказывается, гораздо более непредсказуемая вещь, чем на первый взгляд.

Comment: На самом деле, я думаю тут не всё так сложно, но обсуждать это здесь явно не стоит.

Comment: @VladD,  просто тут нечего оптимизировать. Если отбросить все крестовые заморочки, то в сухом остатке мы получаем функцию `_ZN5cdmem5testfEv`, первым аргументом которой является `this` (а при ее вызове это `pd`). Поскольку функция по этому адресу (и смещениям от него) не обращается, то "падения" не возникает. / Вот и все.

Comment: @avp: Если вы почитаете указанную статью, то увидите ещё один возможный путь: оптимизатор может доказать, что `pd` в точке разыменования есть `null` при всех возможных путях выполнения `main`, поэтому при выполнении гарантированно возникает UB, а значит, можно заменить `main` на `return 0;`.

Comment: @VladD, ну, какой-то компайлер может и пойдет по этому пути, а g++ -O3 все же вызывает testf с обнуленным аргументом (может в GNU думают, что программист хочет исследовать UB? :))

Comment: @avp: Ну, оптимизаторы становятся всё более и более агрессивными. Не зря же, по слухам, ядро не компилируют с -O3.

Comment: @VladD, насколько мне известно -- да, ядро компилируют с -O2 (озон намного опасней кислорода :))

Comment: @avp: На самом деле мне кажется это серьёзной проблемой. Компиляторы стали _намного_ умнее людей, что приводит к проблемам в безопасности. Возможно, нужен специальный, более безопасный диалект C для ядра и компонент, отвечающих за security.

Answer (score 1):

Классический случай UB. Если хотите чтобы 100% программа упала, попробуйте добавить в исследуемую структуру любое поле с данными (например int field = 12;) и обратиться к нему в вызываемой функции.

Answer (score 0):

Вызов невиртуальной функции компилируется в обычный вызов функции с передачей параметром указателя this, в данном случае NULL. Если вы хотите настоящий UB - вызывайте виртуальную функцию.

Comment: Откуда такая информация?

Comment: Это популярный способ имплементации, но вовсе не обязателен по стандарту. UB в любом случае есть UB, креш при этом не обязателен.

Comment: хорошее слово - популярный