# Как получить доступ к private-полям класса извне?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Есть учебное задание, в котором необходимо получить доступ к private-полям класса извне. `struct Cls` дана изначально. Я нагуглил что нужно создать копию структуры, но с `public` методами, а потом через нее стучаться в изначальную.
Вопрос в том как это реализовать? Как можно вернуть ссылку на `private` поля?

```
struct Cls {
  Cls(char c, double d, int i);
  private:
      char c;
      double d;
      int i;
  };



 struct B {
  B(char c, double d, int i);
  public:
      char c1;
      double d1;
      int i1;
 };

// Эта функция должна предоставить доступ к полю c объекта cls.
// Обратите внимание, что возвращается ссылка на char, т. е.
// доступ предоставляется на чтение и запись.
char &get_c(Cls &cls) {

    return ((B*)(&cls))->c1 = 'p';

}

// Эта функция должна предоставить доступ к полю d объекта cls.
// Обратите внимание, что возвращается ссылка на double, т. е.
// доступ предоставляется на чтение и запись.
double &get_d(Cls &cls) {
    /* ... */
}

// Эта функция должна предоставить доступ к полю i объекта cls.
// Обратите внимание, что возвращается ссылка на int, т. е.
// доступ предоставляется на чтение и запись.
int &get_i(Cls &cls) {
    /* ... */
}

int main() {
    Cls cls('h', 2.0, 3);
    char ch = get_c(&cls);
    cout << ch << endl;
}
```

Comment: Это где ж такие учебные задания? Что Вам непонятно в приведенном коде?

Comment: мне непонятно как получить ссылку на прайвэт поля первого класса, использую второй

Comment: `#define private public`

Comment: @zenden2k: UB в чистом виде.

Comment: @VladD, если весь код в одном файле, то точно никакого UB. Update: или это не к defiine'у относилось?

Comment: Пора бы принять какой-нибудь ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Всё [гораздо хуже](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2726221/276994).

Comment: @VladD, препроцессор подставляется до компиляции. Если получившийся код корректен, то ни о каком UB не может быть и речи. Тут тогда явно impementation defined - либо препроцессор компилятора съел этот define, либо нет. О UB можно было бы говорить, если бы мы для заголовочного файла поменяли private на public, а в cpp-файле оставили private (кстати, не уверен, насколько вообще такой финт пройдёт).

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вы говорите о какой-то конкретной имплементации препроцессора. А стандарт запрещает подобные трюки.

Comment: @Vlad. Если компилятор после препроцессора получил код, который соответствует стандарту и сам по себе не содержит UB, то как можно говорить о UB из-за препроцессора? Тут вариантов всего три: 1. define сработал, компилятор получил код без UB и UB нет; 2. define не сработал, компилятор получил корректный код без UB, без подстановки макроса - UB всё равно бы не было, но в нашем случае это ошибка компиляции из-за private; 3. некорректный define был замечен и компиляция отменена. Ни в одном случае получить UB нельзя. Я говорю, что это нельзя назвать UB. Я НЕ говорю, что стандарт это разрешает.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Поведение препроцессора тоже описывается стандартом.

Comment: @VladD, а разве я с этим спорил?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Вы не можете честным и надёжным путём получить доступ к приватным данным. Существуют грубые хаки, наподобие «угадать бинарный лэйаут данных и скастить указатель», которые прямо запрещены стандартом, и дают право компилятору наказать вас в любой момент.

Правильный ответ на вопрос, как получить доступ к приватным данным — никак. Ваш преподаватель либо задаёт вопрос с подвохом, либо плохо знает язык, который преподаёт.

Конкретно в вашем случае, код

```
(B*)(&cls)->c1
```

нарушает strict aliasing rule (правило 3.10/10 [стандарта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417798/10105)).

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/276994)
- [GotW #76: Uses and Abuses of Access Rights](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm).

---

Окей, исходя из развернувшейся дискуссии в ответе @Vlad from Moscow, вопрос о доступе через указатель на «чужой» тип не так уж очевиден даже из стандарта. Как видите, мы покамест не пришли к общему мнению о том, правомерен ли такой доступ по стандарту. В любом случае, доступ к приватным полям — очень плохой стиль программирования, и даже если так *возможно* сделать, делать этого *не нужно*.

---

**Обновление**: Другие ответы: ([[1]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455610/10105), [[2]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455161/10105) и [[3]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455105/10105)) убедили меня в том, что к приватным полям таки можно получить доступ «законным» — то есть, совместимым со стандартом путём. (Впрочем, с трактовкой стандарта в последнем из них я не вполне согласен, но это лишь показывает, что сам по себе стандарт — достаточно большой и не очень ясно написанный текст.)

Тем не менее, любой из приведённых подходов кажется мне грубым хаком, и я бы крайне не рекомендовал пользоваться ими в production-коде. Думаю, будет поучительно, если вы отправите ссылку на это обсуждение вашему преподавателю.

Comment: В приведении указателя к другому типу нет UB. Оно есть в перемешанных обращениях к одним данным через указатели разных типов. В данном случае смешения нет, т. к. первое обращение по указателю нового типа (и его присваивание) делается после последнего по указателю старого. Правило отсутствие смешанных обращений направлено на кэширование значений - если ты меняешь через другой тип, то там значение может взяться из кэшированной копии и оказаться старым. И то компиляторы типа clang'а особо осторожно работают с явными кастами. В данном коде ничего подобного нет, т. е. он корректен и не содержит UB.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Мне кажется, что стандарт с вами не согласен. Насколько я понимаю стандарт, любое обращение к объекту через указатель несовместимого типа — UB.

Comment: Кстати, ещё одна мысль. Если в структуре поле типа double и я обращаюсь к нему через указатель на тип double, то нарушения тоже нет, независимо от того, каким способом я получил этот указатель - хоть с клавиатуры ввёл.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это да, но проблема не в этом, а в `->`, стрелка вычисляет оффсет. В любом случае, если у вас найдётся ссылка на нужный пункт в стандарте, будет круто.

Comment: Похоже, я не прав. http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html (доступна страница в кэше яндекса, оригинал у меня не открывается) Violating Type Rules: It is undefined behavior to cast an int* to a float* and dereference it (accessing the "int" as if it were a "float"). C requires that these sorts of type conversions happen through memcpy: using pointer casts is not correct and undefined behavior results. Но в любом случае, каст корректен, некорректно именно разыменование. Кстати, берём две структуры, делаем memcpy и получаем корректный код - это там явно написано.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, проблема именно в разыменовании.

Comment: Но если мы сделали каст (разыменования нет), добыли адрес нужного поля (теперь тип совпадает) и разыменовали его, то UB нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Хм, а как мы добыли адрес? С чужим типом это вроде бы нельзя?

Comment: Получить для совместимого типа offsetof и сложить с `void*` годится?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Хм. Если есть гарантия, что оффсеты совпадают, то может и сработать даже по стандарту. По-моему, хорошая идея, катит на отдельный ответ.

Comment: Ага, я как раз код дописал :)

Answer (score 9):

Формально можно обмануть компилятор следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>

struct Cls {
  Cls(char c, double d, int i) : c( c ), d( d ), i( i ) {}
  private:
      char c;
      double d;
      int i;
  };



 struct B {
  B(char c, double d, int i) : c1( c ), d1( d ), i1( i ) {}
  public:
      char c1;
      double d1;
      int i1;
 };

char &get_c( Cls &cls ) 
{
    void *p = &cls;

    B *pb = static_cast<B *>( p );

    return pb->c1 = 'A';;
}


int main()
{
    Cls cls('h', 2.0, 3);
    char ch = get_c( cls) ;
    std::cout << ch << std::endl;

}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
A
```

Это совершенно корректный код, так как обе структуры являются `layout-compatible` и согласно стандарту C++ (3.9.2 Compound types)

> 3. ...Pointers to cv-qualified and cv-unqualified versions (3.9.3) of
>      **layout-compatible types** shall have the same value representation and
>      alignment requirements (3.11).

Более подробно:
9.2 Class members:

> 16 Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible
>   if they have the same number of non-static data members and
>   corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have
>   layout-compatible types (3.9).

и 9 Classes:

> 7 A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> — has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or
>   array of such types) or reference,
>
> — has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
>
> — has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data
>   members,
>
> — has no non-standard-layout base classes,
>
> — either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and
>   at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base
>   classes with non-static data members, and — has no base classes of the
>   same type as the first non-static data member.
>
> 8 A standard-layout struct is a standard-layout class defined with the
>   class-key struct or the class-key class. A standard-layout union is a
>   standard-layout class defined with the class-key union

Вы также в `main` могли бы объявить ссылку на объект типа `char`. Вот более наглядная программа благодаря добавлению дружественного оператора вывода

```
#include <iostream>

struct Cls {
  Cls(char c, double d, int i) : c( c ), d( d ), i( i ) {}
  private:
      char c;
      double d;
      int i;
    friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream &os, const Cls &cls )
    {
        return os << "c = " << cls.c << ", d = " << cls.d << ", i = " << cls.i;
    }        
  };



 struct B {
  B(char c, double d, int i) : c1( c ), d1( d ), i1( i ) {}
  public:
      char c1;
      double d1;
      int i1;
 };

char &get_c( Cls &cls ) 
{
    void *p = &cls;

    B *pb = static_cast<B *>( p );

    return pb->c1 = 'A';;
}


int main()
{
    Cls cls('h', 2.0, 3);
    char &ch = get_c( cls) ;
    std::cout << ch << std::endl;
    ch = 'B';

    std::cout << cls << std::endl;
Ъ
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
A
c = B, d = 2, i = 3
```

Comment: Эээ... pointer aliasing?

Comment: @VladD   Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Хм. Всю жизнь думал, что нельзя. Перечитаю стандарт.

Comment: Хм, всё ещё не понимаю. Для начала, почему эти типы layout compatible?

Comment: `has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members` — это вроде бы не выполняется

Comment: @VladD  Это имеется в виду, что внутри одной структуры все нестатические члены имеют тот же самый класс доступа.

Comment: А, понял. Хм, неужели оставлена такая дыра? :-\ Сейчас перепроверю.

Comment: @VladD  Это сделано для связи с другими языками программирования.

Comment: Окей, я согласен, что данные типы layout-compatible. Но почему при этом катит каст через `void*`? В 3.10/10 нет ни слова насчёт layout-compatible, а значит, такой доступ вроде бы всё равно неправомерен.

Comment: @VladD  Указатели имеют то же самое представление и выравнивание. Вы не можете напрямую делать приведение типов, так как нет такого преобразования. Но вы можете это делать через void указатель.

Comment: Но не является ли это UB? Имеет ли компилятор право увидеть, что во всей программе нет ни одного объекта типа `B`, и выкинуть всю процедуру, т. к. не может быть законного обращения к памяти по указателю типа `B*`? То же представление — да, но этого ведь не достаточно? Если идти по дороге UB, можно тогда уж и просто вручную воспользоваться `#define private public #define class struct`

Comment: @VladD  Например, функция malloc возвращает void указатель, не так ли, которые вы преобразуете к указателю требуемого типа.

Comment: @VladD конструктор лишь инициализирует члены класса с фундаментальными типами.

Comment: Ну, с malloc проблем нет — до того, как вы сконструируете объект в выделенной памяти, вы не имеете права обращаться к этой памяти. Указатель держать можно, разыменовывать нельзя, если по адресу реально **нет** объекта нужного типа.

Comment: @VladD  Реально объект существует. Он реинтерпретируется как другая структура.

Comment: ... А реинтерпретация — не противоречит ли она 3.10/10?

Comment: @VladD Вы этом состоит смысл layout-compatible, что вы можете обращаться к структурам, которые были определены в других языках программирования.

Comment: @VladD Я только что задал соответствующий вопрос на форуме по обсуждению стандарта C++. Так что подождем, что скажут в этом отношении специалисты со всего мира.:) Я сообщу о результатах.

Comment: Ого! Круто! Ждём.

Comment: А можно ссылку? Интересно почитать, что пишут гуру.

Comment: @VladD  Попробуйте зайти по этой ссылке https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-discussion

Comment: Ага, открылось, спасибо! (Почему-то не с первого раза.)

Comment: return pb->c1 = 'A';;

не понял эту строчку? зачем return 'A' делать?

Comment: @Александр Дворцов У вас же в исходном примере стоит следующее предложение return ((B*)(&cls))->c1 = 'p'; Я просто заменил 'p' нв 'A' для наглядности и возвратил ссылку на этот объект, которому только что было присвоено новое значение.

Answer (score 8):

Легальный способ - это явная инстанциация шаблона.
Согласно [[temp.spec] p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#general-6):

> Правила доступа не применяются к именам использованным при явных инстанциациях. [ Примечание: в частности, шаблонные аргументы и имена использованные при декларации функции (...) могут быть приватными типами или членами, которые обычно не были бы доступны, и шаблон может быть шаблоном функции-члена класса, которая обычно не была бы доступна.  — конец примечания ]

> (В оригинале: The usual access checking rules do not apply to names in a declaration of an explicit instantiation or explicit specialization (...))

Это можно использовать следующим способом:
Допустим у нас есть класс

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    int field;
    void print() { std::cout << field << '\n'; }
};
```

Мы хотим положить указатели на члены класса `field` и `print` в следующие глобальные переменные.

```
inline int Foo::* Foo_field_ptr;
inline void (Foo::* Foo_print_ptr)();
```

Напишем шаблонный класс, который принимает указатель на глобальную переменную, и какое-то значение.
В инициализаторе поля `_` мы будем присваивать значение переменной.

```
template<auto* Ptr, auto Val>
class SetVar {
    static const bool _;
};

template<auto* Ptr, auto Val>
inline const bool SetVar<Ptr, Val>::_ = (*Ptr = Val, false);
//                              оператор "запятая" ^
```

Теперь мы можем инстанциировать `SetVar` указателем на переменную Foo_field_ptr и указателем на член класса`&Foo::field`, сработает инициализатор `SetVar::_`,  и значение запишется в переменную.

```
template class SetVar<&Foo_field_ptr, &Foo::field>;
template class SetVar<&Foo_print_ptr, &Foo::print>;

int main() {
    Foo x;
    x.*Foo_field_ptr = 42;
    (x.*Foo_print_ptr)();
}
```

---

Альтернативная версия с использованием функции-друга

```
// Привязывает член класса к некоторому типу-тегу,
// и определяет функцию, которая возвращает указатель на член класса.
template<typename Tag, auto MemPtr>
class PrivateMemberAccess {
    friend constexpr auto GetPrivateMemPtr(Tag) {
        return MemPtr;
    }
};

// Всмомогательный тип чтобы писать <T> вместо (T{})
template<typename Tag>
static constexpr auto PrivateMemberPtr = GetPrivateMemPtr(Tag{});
```

Класс-жертва

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    int field;
    void print() { std::cout << field << '\n'; }
};
```

Бойлерплейт для доступа к приватным членам класса

```
struct Foo_field_tag {};
struct Foo_print_tag {};

template class PrivateMemberAccess<Foo_field_tag, &Foo::field>;
template class PrivateMemberAccess<Foo_print_tag, &Foo::print>;

// Если не объявить функцию, то мы не сможем её вызвать.
constexpr auto GetPrivateMemPtr(Foo_field_tag);
constexpr auto GetPrivateMemPtr(Foo_print_tag);
```

Использование

```
int main() {
    Foo x;
    x.*PrivateMemberPtr<Foo_field_tag> = 42;
    (x.*PrivateMemberPtr<Foo_print_tag>)();
}
```

Comment: Огого! Стандарты C++ темны и непонятны. Ужас. А как вы оцениваете более простой идеологически [метод Qwertiy](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455161/10105)?

Comment: Это-то я понимаю. Вроде бы нарушения нету, т. к. фиктивный класс используется лишь для получения `offsetof`, а разыменовывается только `double*`. Вопрос в том, имеем ли мы право разыменонвывать `double*`, который указывает на _поле_? То есть, совместимость `double Class::*` с `double*`.

Comment: Кслассный способ :)

Comment: @VladD, а почему бы нам не иметь такого права? Если бы он был public, то мы могли бы передавать указатель на него в функцию, принимающую указатель на double. Это по сути и есть double - это же не метод, где часть типа с классом прячет передачу this, это просто значение.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Хм, убедили.

Comment: @VladD, я похоже немного ошибся про указатель на double как член класса - судя по коду это то самое offsetof - иначе было бы невозможно скормить шаблону инстанс объекта. Но на правильность рассуждений это не влияет.

Comment: А что-то более приемлемое, без глобальной переменной, возможно? Но, в любом случае, великолепный пример, почему **не нужно использовать C++**.

Comment: @Abyx: Кажется, тогда можно убрать фиктивную переменную `static bool _` и использовать вместо неё `mem_ptr`?

Comment: @Abyx: Я имел в виду, вместо `bool set_member<Getter, P>::_ = (Getter::mem_ptr = P, false);` писать `Getter::mem_ptr set_member<Getter, P, ...>::_ = P;`, как-то так. (Если такое пройдёт.)

Comment: @Abyx: Ой-ой-ой, теперь только понял! `set_member` существует и оказывает сайд-эффекты, но к нему невозможно получить доступ. Мм-да, хорошая лазейка в законе.

Comment: И все-таки я абсолютно не могу понять эту "шаблонную магию". Совершенно не доходит (даже с Helper, т.е. в ответе) как именно  (по шагам) они работают, когда выполняется `i = obj.*g_mem_ptr;` / (а интересно, ТС, ради которого по идее и сделан ответ, всю эту механику понял?)

Comment: Поигрался немного с отладчиком и кодом. Кстати, добиться доступа к нескольким полям (добавил `int j;` в Cls) с помощью "библиотечной" версии не удалось (а вот с "разноименными" копиями Helper -- все получается) / Однако, согласитесь, многовато букв требуется для того, что обеспечивает простая копия Cls со всеми public, которую просто накладываем на оригинал)

Comment: Ну, не знаю. Если делаем полную копию со всеми методами, но вместо private всюду public, то вроде все правильно печатает.

Comment: В теории может, но на практике вряд ли кто-то станет этим заниматься в зависимости от public/private

Answer (score 3):

http://ideone.com/gTyt2Q

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct cls
{
  public:
    cls(char c, double d, int i) : c(c), d(d), i(i) {}
  private:
    char c;
    double d;
    int i;
};

struct copy
{
  public:
    copy(char c, double d, int i);
  public:
    char c;
    double d;
    int i;
};

int main(void)
{
  cls x('1', 2.5, 3);

  printf
  (
    "%c %f %d\n", 
    *(char*)((void*)&x + offsetof(copy, c)),
    *(double*)((void*)&x + offsetof(copy, d)),
    *(int*)((void*)&x + offsetof(copy, i))
  );

  return 0;
}
```

Вроде бы в комментариях пришли к выводу, что этот код не содержит UB, поскольку:

- Структуры с одинаковым набором и последовательностью полей имеют одинаковое внутреннее представление.
- Приведение указателя к другому типу не является UB до тех пор, пока не делается его разыменование. Кроме того, в данном коде приведение делается только к `void*`.
- Добавление смещения к адресу структуры даёт указатель на её поле.
- Указатель на поле приводится к корректному типу, поэтому его разыменование не приводит к UB.

Comment: Может, прибавите пару слов про standard compilance?

Comment: @VladD, написал.

Answer (score 0):

А можно и без функций для доступа (и для разнообразия, а то что-то все про `union` забыли).

```
int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  union u {
    struct Cls hidden;
    struct B   B;
  } *up;


  Cls cls('h', 2.0, 3);
  B b('A', 3.14, 10);
  up = (union u *)&cls;

  cout << up->B.c1 << ' ' << up->B.d1 << ' ' << up->B.i1 << '\n';
  up->B = b;
  cout << up->B.c1 << ' ' << up->B.d1 << ' ' << up->B.i1 << '\n';

}
```

Результат

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ c.cpp -std=c++11
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
h 2 3
A 3.14 10
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Если же использовать `-std=gnu++11`, то union можно сделать безымянным, а приведение типа `up = (typeof(up))&cls;` вот так.

Comment: Так всё равно ж UB. Из `union` по стандарту можно читать вроде только то, что туда фактически положено. (Трюки для превращения double в байты не соответствуют стандарту.)

Comment: @VladD, ну ведь на практике это работает. А где не заработает, там надо либо сменить компилятор, либо ... придумать что-нибудь еще (по обстановке). Все равно ведь абсолютная переносимость программ это нечто идеальное (вроде коммунизма)

Comment: Ну, это на gcc. Плюс если там реально UB, то в любой момент (то есть в любой новой версии компилятора) оптимизатор может броситься на амбразуру грудью и снести всю функцию.

Comment: @VladD, в таком случае придется вспомнить ассемблер -)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно применить паттерн "Паблик Морозов"

```
#define private public
#define protected public
#include "your class header.h"
#undef private
#undef protected
```

После такого подключения все закрытые поля класса, объявленного в Yourclass header.h станут пабликами.

Comment: почему-то не сработало в Xcode

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
#ifdef BOOST_TEST_MODULE
public:
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже, наверное, неактуально, но всё же оставлю здесь свой вариант)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class lol
{
    int x;
public:
    lol()
    {
        x = 5;
    }
    void pr()
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    lol big;
    big.pr();
    int* x = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&big);
    cout << *x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

пробежался по ответам, reinterpret_cast нигде не увидел