# Как присвоить значение полю класса из вне?

Tags: c++

Есть класс:

```
class A
{
    private:
       int i;
};
```

Нужно вне класса присвоить i некоторое значение с помощью прокси-класса. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Кроме вас никто не знает, что в данном случае означает прокси-класс. Поэтому вам, как говорится, все карты в руки! Дерзайте!:)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(шаблон_проектирования)#C.2B.2B

Comment: надо короч передать управление прокси класу и он присвоит типо нам так сказали

Comment: Я лишь могу предположить, что имеется в виду что-то вроде такого  class A { private: int i; };
    struct B { int i; };
    
    A a;
    
    reinterpret_cast<B &>( a ).i = 10;

Answer (score 2):

Ну, может и не в тему прокси, но как вариант "наследование":   =)

```
class A
{ 
private: 
    int i;
protected:
    void set_val(int x) 
    { i = x; }
public:
    int get_val(void) const
    { return (i); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   B()
   { A::set_val(0); }

   void set_value(int x)
   { set_val(x); }

   int get_value(void) const
   { return get_val(); }
};

void func(void)
{
    B b;
    int xx = 777, yy = 0;

    b.set_value(xx);
    yy = b.get_value();
}
```

Comment: С форматированием пока не получается...    :(

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, примерно:

```
class ProxyA;

class A
{
  public:
    A() : i(0) {}
    int i() { return i; }

  private:
    int i;

  friend class ProxyA;
};

class ProxyA
{
  public:
  static void set(A* a, int i)
  {
    a->i = i;
  }
};

// использование:
A obj;
std::cout << "before: " << obj.i() << std::endl; // вывод: 0
// obj.i = 1; - если раскомментировать, здесь будет ошибка при компиляции
ProxyA::set(&obj, 1);
std::cout << "after: " << obj.i() << std::endl; // вывод: 1
```

Comment: А вообще, вы бы по-точнее написали, что вам необходимо получить.

Comment: Лучше конечно такие задачки самому решать. Основы основ. Почитайте любую книгу по С++.

Comment: @MisHa Ответ не соответствует вашему вопросу. У вас в вопросе задан конкретный класс с отсутствием доступа к своему члену данных. Поэтому никакой прокси здесь не поможет.:).

Comment: @MisHa "настоящему програмисту кинги не нужны" - А чем тогда настоящие программисты заняты в туалете? Или они с ноутбуком ходят в туалет?

Comment: @MisHa, и все же класс `A` в ответе отличается от класса `A` в вопросе (наличием строчки `friend class ProxyA;`, которая в корне меняет дело).

Comment: Согласен с @avp, после **friend class** можно ничего не читать. А вот по поводу доступа к приватным членам класса, [такой вопрос уже был](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455087/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-private-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5/).

Comment: @mega, согласен, введение `friend class` - грубый хак. Но в данном вопросе считаю, что не нужно подходить с таким формализмом. Совершенно очевидно, что вопрос - студенческая задача, где преподаватель просит, чтобы студенты проявили немного более знаний, чем он им дал, а не разрешали неразрешимое. Также совершенно очевидно, что студенты должны сами решать такие задачи и задавать вопросы "почему мой код не работает/работает не так?", а не просить готового решения.

Comment: Да, @aleks.andr, возможно Вы правы. С точки зрения стандарта, мне Ваш вариант нравится больше, чем сам вопрос о доступе к приватным членам класса. Но и саму задачу можно трактовать двояко. Голосую за то, что вопрос "требует правки".