Как получить доступ к protected-полям класса извне?
В кратце, такая дилема. Дан код:
class SecretClass {
private:
    std::string token;
protected:
    void SetTokenTo(SecretClass& another) {
        another.token = token;
    }
public:
    SecretClass(const std::string& token) : token(token) {};
    std::string GetToken() const {
        return token;
    }
};

void externalFunction(SecretClass& secret) {
        
}

int main() {
    SecretClass secret("FUTURE");
    externalFunction(secret);
    assert(secret.GetToken() == "CODE");
}

и нужно написать функцию externalFunction так, чтобы она заменяла один token на другой. Я думаю что для этого нужно как то получить доступ к функции SetTokenTo, но я не знаю как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста!
P.S. Забыл добавить что можно дописывать что хочешь главное не трогать main и SecretClass.

Это с собеседования?

Извините, но можно подробности? Зачем (задание, интересно etc)? Почему просто не поменять код? Если нельзя менять модификатор, можно использовать дружбу? Какие ограничения на решение? просто чтоб не оказаться в ситуации, когда после ответа начинается "я забыл сказать, что так нельзя"...

Тогда просто интерпретируй указатель на класс, как указатель на строку, т к. первое поле строка, все сработает .. и измени ее

https://ideone.com/y3rf6G

@evo Вот потому и спрашиваю — например, можно ли использовать решение, которое формально UB :)

Кто сказал что это ub?

Я :) Кто сказал, что во всех реализациях адрес объекта и адрес поля в объекте совпадают? Где это в стандарте?

Подсказка: SecretClass не явлется final и имеет protected метод SetTokenTo для изменения поля.

@evo Адрес объекта и адрес первого поля в нем гарантированно совпадает только у standard-layout классов, и нет гарантии, что std::string является таким классом.

Ладно, раз уже идея прозвучала... :) https://ideone.com/5StP2w

Ну раз уж пошла такая пьянка, то предложу и свой вариант: https://godbolt.org/z/W635Yz61a

Вот тут про private - с protected тоже должно работать. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455087/178988 @Harry, и есть варианты без UB xD

В общем, ларчик просто открывался:
void externalFunction(SecretClass& secret) {
    SecretClass abc("CODE");
    secret = abc;
}

Все было слишком просто, чтобы быть правдой.
