# Гарантия инициализации нулевыми значениями

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Все статические/глобальные переменные примитивных типов приравниваются к нулевыми значениями, автоматические/динамические переменные не гарантируют приведение к нулевому значению, а как на счет массивов и пользовательских объектов, всегда ли гарантируется исполнение конструктора по умолчанию (если оно есть), а как на счет массивов заполненных пользовательским типом? (при различных способах их создании)

`char msg[10] = { 97 }; //А тут гарантируются что все, кроме нулевого элемента, будут равны 0?`

При каких условиях переменные заполняются нулевыми значениями?
Где это можно найти в стандарте?

Comment: Просто совет практика. Для переносимости не  полагайтесь на стандарты, не жалейте `#ifdef`-ов и не ленитесь писать хорошие `configure`. А главное, тщательно тестируйте свой код для всех обещанных Вами платформ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вам может подойти aggregate initialization:

```
T array[10] = {};
```

Согласно [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (перевод мой, нерелевантный текст пропущен):

Результат aggregate initialization (*в нашем случае, инициализации всего массива*):

- Если [...] список инициализации пуст, [...] элементы инициализируются [...] пустыми списками, что означает [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Результат value initialization (*в нашем случае, инициализации элементов массива*):

1. Если тип `T` есть класс без конструктора по умолчанию, с пользовательским конструктором по умолчанию или с удалённым  class конструктором по умолчанию, происходит [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).
2. Если тип `T` есть класс с конструктором по умолчанию, который не является ни пользовательским, ни удалённым (то есть, это может быть класс с неявно созданным конструктром по умолчанию или созданным при помощи `= default`), происходит zero initialization, а затем, если у него нетривиальный конструктор по умолчанию, default initialization (то есть, вызов этого конструктора).
3. Если тип `T` сам по себе массив, у его элементов рекурсивно происходит value initialization.
4. В противном случае, у объекта происходит [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

И наконец, default initialization:

- Если тип `T` есть класс, выбирается конструктор, соответствующий пустому списку аргументов. Этот конструктор (он будет одним из конструкторов по умолчанию) исполняется.
- Если `T` сам по себе массив, для каждого элемента применяется рекурсивно  default initialization.
- В остальных случаях ничего не происходит. Значения, с которыми инициализируется объект, не определены.

---

Таким образом, для массива объектов класса с конструктором по умолчанию произойдёт цепочка aggregate initialization массива → → value initialization элементов массива → default initialization элементов массива → конструктор по умолчанию.

---

Все эти данные, написанные ещё более сухим языком, вы можете найти и [в стандарте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417798/10105).

---

Финальный совет (важно!): убедитесь, что компилятор, которым вы пользуетесь, соответствует стандарту. Компиляторы вполне могут не очень хорошо поддерживать стандарт. Особенно это касается немейнстримных компиляторов.

Comment: char msg[10] = { 97 };  А тут может гарантироваться что все, кроме нулевого элемента, будут равны 0?

Comment: @relaxGalaxy, да