# Преобразование char -> int цифры и буквы

Tags: c++, c, стандарт, language-lawyer

Довольно часто в коде можно увидеть строки типа

```
char cdigit = '8';
int idigit = cdigit - '0';
```

Реже, но также встречается

```
char letter = 'd';
int letter_number = letter - 'a';
```

Открываем Страуструпа "Язык прогрммирования С++" специальное издание, "Бином-Пресс", 2008. Цитата (стр 110):

> Небезопасно считать, ... что символы алфавита непрерывны (в стандарте EBCDIC между i и j имеется разрыв)

У Кернигана и Ритчи вышеприведенный код (по крайней мере по цифрам) встречается регулярно.

Собственно вопрос по цифрам: обязательно ли корректен код `idigit = cdigit - '0'`?

Comment: Собственно нашел http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868496/how-to-convert-char-to-integer-in-c. Там утверждается, что текущий стандарт С гарантирует корректность. Ответ от 09 года.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за цитаты из стандартов. Есть одна проблема - я в замешательстве, кому ставить галочку) Ну почему нельзя две поставить?

Comment: Причём один ответ по C, а второй по C++ :)

Comment: @VladD, причем цитаты совпадают досимвольно))

Comment: Кто-нибудь может кинуть ссылку на реализацию `atoi`. Интересно, как там написано. Я нашел только хедеры.

Comment: Нашел (itoa, но неважно) : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/itoa

Comment: Ну, там имплементация K&R, они вполне могли писать под их текущее hardware. Язык тогда только начинался, и о кроссплатформенности никто не думал особенно.

Comment: И кстати "символы алфавита" и "цифры" немного разные вещи. Я еще не видел кодировок, где цифры не шли бы подряд. А EBCDIC, да, прикольный такой шрифт, особенно русские локализации, где одинаковые по начертанию буквы всегда латинские :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В [стандарте C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417798/10105) §2.3/4 гласит:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

то есть

> В обоих наборе символов исходного текста и времени выполнения, значение каждого символа после `0` в приведённом выше списку десятичных цифр должно быть на единицу больше предыдущего.

(перевод мой). Приведённый в §2.3/1 набор цифр таков:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Это гарантирует последовательность значений кодов цифр.

Comment: Ну, и я так понимаю, что за `letter -'a'` нужно бить по рукам?

Comment: @andy.37: Насчёт `letter` ничего в стандарте не нашёл, так что по идее да, надо бить по рукам.

Comment: @andy.37: Плюс EBCDIC является явным контрпримером.

Answer (score 4):

Нашел всё-таки такую фразу в сишном Стандарте (C99):

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>   each character after0in the above list of decimal digits shall be one
>   greater than the value of the previous.