# Преобразование char в int

Tags: c++

Как элементу массива `int` присвоить элемент массива типа `char`.

**Обновление**

В массиве типа `char` хранятся цифры.

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже существует: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470844/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-char-int-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

```
char cArr[] = "foo";
char iArr[8] = { 0 };
iArr[0] = cArr[0];
```

Присваивает первому элементу массива из int первый элемент массива из char.

Answer (score -2):

Нашел решение:

```
char c[] = { "322345" };
int i[10];
i[0] = c[0] - '0';
```