# Удаление нулевого указателя

Tags: c++

Что происходит при попытке удаления нулевого указателя через `delete`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ровным счётом ничего.

---

Формальная ссылка на [стандарт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/10105), §5.3.5/2:

> In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). [...] In the second alternative (delete array), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array new-expression.

Перевод:

> Для первого варианта (`delete object`), значение операнда `delete` **может быть значением null-указателя**, указателем на объект, не являющийся массивом, созданный при помощи `new`, или указателем на подобъект (1.8), представляющий базовый класс такого объекта (см. клаузу 10). [...] Во втором случае (`delete array`), значение операнда **может быть значением null-указателя** или значением указателя, полученного при помощи выражения `new` для массивов.

---

Из [официального C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-handles-null):

> ### Нужно ли мне проверять на `null` перед `delete p`?
>
> Нет!
>
> Язык C++ гарантирует, что `delete p` ничего не будет делать, если `p` есть `null`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete. Там написано, что не определено, вызывается ли `deallocation function`, но гарантируется, что она не делает ничего в случе нулевого указателя. Опередили). Если такого вопроса не было, то он, ИМХО, полезен, я плюсану.

Comment: Тут, кстати, таки не написано, что же происходит в случае вызова `delete nullptr`, написано только, что это можно делать.

Comment: @vika: Деструктор не вызывается: объекта-то нет! Значение указателя не меняется в любом случае, вне зависимости от того, был там `nullptr` или нет.

Comment: @VladD Разве при удалении ненулевого указателя его значение определено? Обычно советуют писать `p=0` после `delete p`.

Comment: @andy.37: Это есть (неявно) в §5.3.5/6, но цитировать ещё тот текст было бы слишком.

Comment: @vika: При удалении ненулевого указателя значение остаётся таким же, как и было. Советуют присваивать `nullptr` только для того, чтобы вы по ошибке не могли использовать удалённый объект. (Ну или удалить его второй раз, это тоже нельзя.)

Comment: @vika: Пожалуйста!