# Как я могу узнать количество выделенной памяти под массив char? (Динамическая память)

Tags: c++

Как мне узнать количество char-ов которые выделены с помощью new??

Comment: конкретезируйте вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: Никак нельзя, хранить отдельно.

Comment: либо используйте с++ способ - `std::string`, `std::vector<char>`

Comment: [man malloc_usable_size](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html) (или [malloc_size](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/malloc_size.3.html) в apple или [_msize](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize?view=msvc-170) в винде)

Comment: вот только это для malloc. Да, new/new[] под капотом может использовать malloc напрямую, а может и нет. Плюс нет абсолютно никакой гарантии, что тот указатель, который возвращает malloc, будет возвращает и с помощью new.

Comment: @KoVadim стандартный оператор `new[]` действительно внутри себя вызывает `malloc()` и если та возвращает `NULL`, бросает исключение. Более того, если выделяется массив классов, содержащих деструктор, то длина массива помещается перед возвращаемым оператором `new[]` указателем - т.е., сам указатель на такой массив смещается относительно выделенной области на 4 байта (во всяком случае в g++ так). Подзырено в дизассемблере))

Comment: насколько я знаю по опыту, gcc и vs по разному реализует поведение new[]/delete[]. Более того, студия в отладочном режиме оставляет достаточно информации, что бы понять, по указателю массив или просто один объект, а в релизе все достаточно чистенько и ничего лишнего. И да, оно вызывает malloc, но я не видел требования это делать.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно (но я могу ошибаться) не существует документированного способа узнать размер динамически выделенного массива по его указателю. Соответственно, возможны следующие варианты:

1. Вместе с указателем на массив сохранять размер последнего в переменной. Например:

   `char* pMyArray = new char[NUM_CHARS];`

   `int myArrayLen = NUM_CHARS;`
2. Следует из (1) - использовать класс-обёртку, представляющий пару "указатель на массив, размер массива". Например, в черновом варианте это может выглядеть так:

   ```
    template <typename T=char>
    class CDynamicArray
    {
        T* m_pData;
        int m_length;

    public:
        CDynamicArray()
        {
            m_pData = nullptr;
        }

        T* Create(int length)
        {
            m_pData = new T[length];
            m_length = length;
            return m_pData;
        }

        void Delete()
        {
            if (m_pData)
            {
                delete[] m_pData;
                m_pData = nullptr;
            }
        }

        T* GetData()
        {
            return m_pData;
        }

        int GetLength()
        {
            return m_length;
        }

        ~CDynamicArray()
        {
            Delete();
        }

        CDynamicArray(const CDynamicArray&) = delete;
    };
   ```
3. Не изобретать велосипед, а использовать уже готовое решение `std::vector`(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: ну хотя бы правило трех соблюли. А то до первого копирования

Comment: @KoVadim ну это же черновой вариант. Если не копировать, то вполне рабочий.

Comment: Скажем так, это ужасный вариант. Вот функция create не нужна. Этим конструктор должен заниматься. А если эту функцию позовут дважды? В деструкторе лишний if и присваивание.

Comment: Да да, если не копировать этот код себе, то вполне нормально будет

Comment: @KoVadim конструктор-то этим может заниматься, однако тут есть один минус: вам не остаётся другого способа создать массив, кроме как при объявлении переменной класса, что бывает далеко не всегда удобно. Вариант с Create/Delete более гибкий (к тому же ничто не мешает добавить второй коструктор, вызывающий `Create()`). Насчёт вызова метода `Create()` дважды согласен, есть косяк - вариант же черновой. Исправляется с помощью if/assert. "Лишний if" в деструкторе погоды не делает, но от утечки памяти защищает. Хотя в своём коде для этой цели я использую assert, который никогда лишним не бывает))

Comment: от какой утечки защищает if в деструкторе?

Comment: @KoVadim если мы забыли вызвать метод `Delete()`, то деструктор его вызовет, и память будет освобождена. Если мы не забыли вызвать метод `Delete()`, то повторный его вызов в деструкторе погоды не сделает.

Comment: @KoVadim а вообще в деструкторе можно разместить только `assert (m_pData==nullptr);` - в этом случае избегаем повторной проверки, однако метод `Delete()` придётся вызывать обязательно...

Comment: [Удаление нулевого указателя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472992).

Comment: если m_pData == nullptr, тогда `delete m_pData;` работает нормально. Да, там ещё есть бяка. если позвать `Create(...)`, потом `Delete()`, а потом `GetLength()`, то будет неожиданно.

Comment: @KoVadim  а не надо звать `Delete()`, а потом `GetLength()`. Ну ёлки-палки, мой пример здесь передаёт только смысл! В допиленном до ума виде он раза в три больше будет и новичка может отпугнуть!

Comment: @wololo благодарю))

Comment: @LShadow77 исправленный вариант занимает сильно меньше места. а "не нужно звать" - это неверный ответ. Если бы хотя бы зануляли размер...

Comment: @KoVadim я поленился занулить размер, ровно как написать конструктор копирования, вставить проверочные ассерты и директивы условной компиляции для проверки `NDEBUG`, добавить перегруженных операторов и методов для удобства в работе. Если исправленный вариант это `std::vector`, то тогда да, меньше места получится))