# Явное указание постоянства ссылок, в чем смысл?

Tags: c++, ссылки, const

Как известно, ссылки нельзя переназначать, поскольку они все время ссылаются на один и тот же объект и, следовательно, всегда постоянны. Однако синтаксис С++ **допускает** существование постоянных ссылок:

```
int var = 33;
int const & r1 = var; // ссылка на константу
int & const r2 = var; // постоянная ссылка
```

**r1**

В случае с ссылками на константы, все достаточно очевидно.
Если аргумент передаётся в функцию "*по ссылке*", то модификатор **const**, может использоваться для защиты значения от случайных изменений в процессе написания кода программы.

**r2**

А вот в чем смысл явного указания постоянства ссылки?
И где это может применяться на практике мне не понятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC (gcc-5.1) на ideone [не компилирует](http://ideone.com/J7t0Zl) ваш код:

> ```
> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':  
> prog.cpp:8:17: error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'int&'  
>      int & const r2 = var; // постоянная ссылка
> ```

Visual Studio 2015 при компиляции выдаёт предупреждение:

> test.cpp(11): warning C4227: anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored

---

[Текущий стандарт, 8.3.2/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1) (кстати, ссылка на него [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417798/10105)), говорит об этом следующее:

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef-name ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or decltype-specifier ([dcl.type.simple]), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

Таким образом, `const`, относящий к ссылке, либо недопустим, либо будет проигнорирован.

Comment: подход GCC мне нравится больше, так как несмотря на то, что синтаксис языка допускает такую конструкцию, с точки зрения здравого смысла - это высказывание также неоднозначно, как и "масло маслянное".   В Visual Studio, тоже уже проверил, const просто игнорируется, с указанием предупреждения C422. VladD, спасибо за оперативный и точный ответ по теме!

Comment: @Michael: Кроме этого, поведение как у GCC требуется стандартом. Думаю, MSVC сделали так для обратной совместимости.

Comment: @Michael: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Ваш вопрос как-будто построен на неявном предположении, что допустимость такой конструкции с точки зрения *грамматики языка* каким-то образом подразумевает ее "нужность" или "осмысленность".

Это неверное предположение.

Грамотный дизайн языка как раз и требует выбора разумного распределения областей ответственности между формальным синтаксисом (т.е. грамматикой) и дополнительными правилами, описываемыми отдельно, "на словах". Попытки реализовать всевозможные подобные ограничения целиком на уровне грамматики языка привели бы к неимоверно переусложненной грамматике. В данном случае, очевидно, было принято решение не пытаться реализовывать это ограничение на уровне грамматики.

Спецификация языков С и С++ содержат огромное количество примеров таких ситуаций, где ограничения, которые можно было бы отнести к чисто синтаксическим (возможно с определенной натяжкой), тем не менее реализуются не на уровне грамматики языка, а в виде отдельно описываемых ограничений.

Например, в языке С (и, до относительно недавнего времени, в С++) запрещалось использовать оператор "запятая" в константных выражениях. Однако несмотря на то, что грамматики этих языков имеют отдельные нетерминальные символы для "константного выражения", этот запрет реализовался на уровне грамматики только для "запятых" верхнего уровня. А запрет на использование более глубоких "запятых" (внутри скобок) в грамматике не отражен, а сформулирован в спецификации языка "на словах", ибо выстраивать совершенно независимую под-грамматику константных выражений было бы слишком расточительно.

Comment: Ну, это предположение обычно достаточно разумно, хороший язык должен по возможности минимизировать возможности для бессмысленных конструкций. Пример: http://ideone.com/llaR5n

Comment: На счет того, что ограничения приводят к усложнению - это весьма спорно. Мне всегда казалось, что наоборот. Например, в Python выражения не заканчиваются точкой с запятой, это ограничение на уровне синтаксиса позволяет не совершать набивших оскомину ошибок, в виде пропущенных или наоборот избыточных символов " ; ". Есть масса других примеров, но формат комментария не позволяет привести их все.

Comment: @Michael,  только в питоне пришлось добавить оператор pass

Comment: @Michael: В С++ *выражения* тоже не заканчиваются `;`. В С++ `;` - это завершающий символ некоторых типов *statements*, да и то не всех.

Comment: @Michael: Я пользуюсь стандартной терминологией языков С и С++, в которых *statement* - фундаментальное и четко определенное понятие. Никаких трудностей с подтверждением моего утверждения нет.

Comment: Я понимаю, но мы в данном случае говорим на русском, а не английском языке ;)

Comment: @Michael: Причина использования мною английского термина *statement* как раз и заключается в том, что для него до сих пор не придумали адекватного перевода на русский язык. В литературе его обычно переводят как *оператор*, что порождает очевидный (и, по моему мнению, неприемлемый) конфликт с термином *operator* (который тоже переводится как *оператор*). Поэтому, несмотря на то, что я обеими руками за использование русских терминов в русском тексте, во избежание неоднозначности толкования в чувствительных конктестах я предпочитаю иногда явно использовать непереведенный вариант *statement*.

Comment: Наверно statement, лучше определить как _утверждение_. Вопрос исчерпан, ответы даны. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: **Инстру́кция** или **опера́тор** (англ. _statement_) — наименьшая автономная часть языка программирования; команда. **Выражение** (англ. _expression_)  — комбинация значений, констант, переменных, операторов и функций, которая может быть интерпретирована в соответствии с правилами конкретного языка.

Comment: @Michael: Вот и вы пытаетесь перевести *statement* как *оператор*. А как тогда вы предлагаете переводить *operator*?

Comment: Это не я, это википедиа. Я то как раз с вами согласен, что _оператор_ не совсем уместно, больше подходит слово _инструкция_. Тем более, что это практически синонимы.
(https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)