# Объявление и определение функции (порядок размещения)

Tags: c++, функции

В каждой единице трансляции, *объявление* функции обязано предшествовать её вызову. Если это условие выполняется, то порядок размещения *определения* уже не имеет особого значения.

Какой вариант предпочтительней и почему?
(*сначала функция объявлена, а затем определена или наоборот*)

```
void someFunction(); // declaration
void someFunction() { cout << "hello" << endl; }

int main()
{
    someFunction(); // function call                
    return 0;
}
```

**или**

```
void someFunction() { cout << "hello" << endl; }
void someFunction(); // declaration

int main()
{
    someFunction(); // function call                
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Насчет того, где взять текст стандарта, посмотрите этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417797/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82-c. Впринципе вам вполне сойдет и последний опубликованный черновик, отличий от финального стандарта там не так и много, и они совсем не критические.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Какой вариант предпочтительней и почему? (сначала функция объявлена, а затем определена или наоборот)

---

> Хотелось бы узнать причину именно такого порядка размещения. Что это? удобство восприятия программы, отдельное положение стандарта языка, код в этом случае быстрее компилируется или есть ещё какая-то причина?

Причина та же самая, по которой вообще в язык добавлена возможность объявлять функции без их определения.

Представьте что возможности объявить (без определения!) функции нет. И вам надо написать две функции, вызывающие друг друга:

```
void SomeFirstFunction(int n)
{
    cout << n << endl;
    SomeSecondFunction(n);
}

void SomeSecondFunction(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        SomeFirstFunction(n - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    SomeFirstFunction(5);
}
```

Компилятор разбирает файл сверху вниз. Он доходит до строки

```
SomeSecondFunction(n);
```

В этот момент он понятия не имеет, что это за `SomeSecondFunction` и какие параметры она принимает - она ведь еще не определена. И он падает с ошибкой:

```
In function 'void SomeFirstFunction(int)':
error: 'SomeSecondFunction' was not declared in this scope
```

Перестановка местами `SomeSecondFunction` и `SomeFirstFunction`, очевидно, не поможет.

Поэтому в язык добавлен хак - вы можете сказать компилятору "`SomeSecondFunction` - это функция вот с такими параметрами, и она будет определена где-то ниже. Или даже не ниже, а вообще в другом файле - вобщем, смело считай это функцией, генерируй код для ее вызова, потом линковщик разберется где эта функция на самом деле лежит".

```
// предупредили компилятор
void SomeSecondFunction(int n);

void SomeFirstFunction(int n)
{
    cout << n << endl;
    // компилятор спокойно сгенерировал вызов еще не определенной (но объявленной!) функции
    SomeSecondFunction(n);
}

void SomeSecondFunction(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        SomeFirstFunction(n - 1);
    }
}
```

При этом нет никакого смысла в объявлении `SomeFirstFunction` после ее определения - компилятор и так знает что это за функция, ему от еще одного объявления уже известного факта лучше не станет.

---

А вот в примерах из вашего вопроса объявление полностью избыточно. Т.е. ни один из этих вариантов не предпочтительней - они оба бессмысленны, т.к. эквивалентны варианту вообще без declaration:

```
void someFunction() { cout << "hello" << endl; }

int main()
{
    someFunction(); // function call                
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Делать "наборот" нет никакого смысла. Потому что определение функции уже включает в себя объявление.

Причина, по которой нужно объявлять до ее использования очень проста. Когда компилятор встречает вызов функции, ему нужно коректно передать параметры, а также правильно сформировать их "проталкивание" в стек/регистры. А также и решить, кто будет "подчищать" стек после вызова.

Старый си допускал использование функций до их определений/объявлений, но при этом он считал, что все аргументы функции типа int и возвращаемое значение такое же.

***UPD***

кратко. Это запрещено стандартом явно

> 3.2 One definition rule [basic.def.odr]
>
> 1 No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration
> type, or template.

расширено, но сумбурно

В теории, все функции можно разместить так, что бы вызываемые функции были выше (раньше) вызываемых. Это конечно требует дополнительных телодвижений (читать: компиляция будет дольше или нужно ручками все будет расставлять), но возможно. Либо добавлять определение к каждой единице, но это также сильно удлинит компиляцию. Плюс возникает риск того, что в разных единицах компиляции будут разные версии одной и той же функции (из за дефайнов, а это уже весело) либо просто будет дублирование кода, который линковщику ещё и убрать нужно. Поэтому это и запрещено стандартом (

Просто выделение объявлений позволяет делать компиляцию в паралель (или даже на разных машинах). Минимизируется наличие дубликатов функций (inline функции могут дублироваться).

Comment: Всё таки, если быть до конца честным, определение будет являться, также и объявлением, в случае отсутствия последнего. Иначе, данные понятия были бы эквивалентны и не было бы смысла в их разделении. Про использование (вызов) функции, я в курсе. Спасибо конечно )) но вопрос был не про это.

Comment: Тогда уточните вопрос.

Comment: Часто рекомендуют вначале объявлять, а потом определять. Но не указывают оснований для этого. Или пишут, желательно объявлять, потом определять. Но не объясняют почему желательно. Хотелось бы узнать причину именно такого порядка размещения. Что это? удобство восприятия программы, отдельное положение стандарта языка, код в этом случае быстрее компилируется или есть ещё какая-то причина?