# Переопределение имени глобальной переменной

Tags: c++, c++11

Почему оно работает? Слышал об предварительном объявлении, но это явно другой случай. Или в чистом виде UB?

[Сам код на IdeOne](https://ideone.com/4zG78G)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int x = 5;

int main(){
    int x[x];
    cout << "OK!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Локальная переменная скрывает глобальную. Что не так-то?)

Comment: В момент объявления локальной x - массива имеется единственное объявление x - константы. *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Дело в том, что `[x]` является частью объявления типа переменной, где `x` пока еще не обозначает локальную переменную, но как только объявление заканчивается `x` уже будет обозначать именно локальную переменную `int x[x]{x}; // ошибка`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, это не UB. Согласно [стандарту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/10105), раздел 6.3.2, клауза 2 упоминает в точности ваш пример:

```
const int  i = 2;
{ int  i[i]; }
```

В нём определяется массив из двух целых чисел внутри блока.

---

Полная цитата из стандарта (перевод мой):

1. Точка декларации имени находится непосредственно за её полным декларатором (...) и перед инициализатором (если он есть), за исключением замечаний ниже.
   [ Пример:

   ```
   unsigned char x = 12;
   { unsigned char x = x; }
   ```

   Здесь второй `x` инициализируется своим собственным (неопределённым) значением. — конец примера ]
2. [ Замечание: Имя из внешней области действует вплоть до точки декларации имени, которое его перекрывает. [ Пример:

   ```
   const int  i = 2;
   { int  i[i]; }
   ```

   определяет внутриблоковый массив из двух целых. — конец примера ] — конец замечания ]

Comment: Интересно 1) в си тоже так? 2) почему не решились всюду брать инициализатор из внешней области (точнее ближайший уже инициализированный `x`)

Comment: @avp: Думаю, что тоже так, в конце-концов, синтаксис разрабатывали, чтобы он был общим.

Comment: @avp: Думаю, они хотели дать возможность в инициализаторе ссылаться на себя. Например: `void* p = { (void*)p, NULL }`. Без этого сослаться на себя было бы сложно.

Comment: Если честно, я этот пример не понял. Насколько я понимаю, `p` тут инициализируется нулем. На самом деле ссылка на себя больше всего мешает в макросах, поскольку передаваемое имя неизвестно.

Comment: @avp: Тьфу, ошибся. Я имел в виду `void* p[] = { (void*)p, NULL }`. Массив указателей.