# Оператор присваивания и ссылки с++

Tags: c++, ссылки, оператор-присваивания

```
int x = 2;
int y = x;
int &z = x;
```

Собственно, буду краток: почему переменной y присваивается **значение** переменной *х*, а *z* - её ссылка ? В с++ существует какое-то скрытое преобразование со стороны оператора присваивания, и в случае с переменной *y*, он присваивает ей **значение**, полученное по адресу, ассоциированному с *х*, а в случае с *&z* - сам адрес ? Буду рад любой качественной литературе на эту тему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее наоборот.

`x` является адресуемым выражением, lvalue. Когда вы инициализируете другую переменную, то lvalue «понижается» до значения, rvalue, и это самое значение присваивается другой переменной. А вот когда вы инициализируете ссылку, то lvalue как раз для неё и нужно, и оно берётся без понижения.

Заметьте, что у вас речь идёт не о присвоении, а именно об инициализации. При присвоении ссылке снова необходимо значение, rvalue, и оно записывается в переменную, на которую ссылается ссылка.

```
int x = 2;
int y = 55;
int& z = x; // z - ссылка на x
z = y; // z всё ещё ссылка на x, значение x поменялось на 55
```

---

Это объяснение на пальцах. Более подробные объяснения есть [в книжках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/10105), а уж совершенно точные (а также ужасно формальные и скучные) определения найдутся в [стандарте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/10105).

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря Вам наткнулся на такую вещь как lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, дальше уже пойдет, думаю, одно за другим в изучении темы.

Comment: @VyacheslavMikhailov: Угу, правильно наткнулись, именно оно тут и происходит. // Пожалуйста!