# Почему inline-функции, определённые в заголовочных файлах не дублируются при линковке?

Tags: c++, функции, inline, линковка

Я прочёл такой факт насчёт "обычных" и inline- функций:

> В предыдущих главах мы не раз говорили, что вы не должны определять функции в заголовочных файлах, так как если вы подключаете один заголовок с определением функции в несколько файлов .cpp, то определение функции также будет скопировано несколько раз. Затем, при соединении файлов, линкер выдаст ошибку, что вы определяете одну и ту же функцию больше одного раза.
>
> Однако, встроенные функции освобождаются от этого правила, так как дублирования в исходном коде не происходит — определение функции одно, и никакого конфликта при соединении линкером файлов .cpp возникнуть не должно.

Почему нельзя определять функции в header'е, понятно: произойдёт "multiple definition" при линковке нескольких модулей, включающих этот хэдер. Но из текста совсем не понятно, почему это правило не работает для inline-функций. Я понял это так: "inline-функции не дублируются, потому что они не дублируются". Бред.

Я, конечно, могу принять во внимание этот факт как должное, и всё, но всё таки хочется понять, почему так происходит, а исчерпывающего объяснения этот текст не даёт.

Comment: При нормальной компиляции вместо вызова inline-функции вставляется ее содержимое, а при ненормальной просто формируются новые имена для вызова одной и той же функции

Comment: Т.е. определение inline-функции в тексте программы нужно только для компилятора и не имеет отношения объектному файлу после компиляции?

Comment: Все слова ЯП влияют на объектный код, другой вопрос как. Это слово служит для дополнительного указания компилятору в оптимизации кода (замена вызова функции его содержимым).

Comment: @AlexanderChernin , по факту сейчас слово inline вроде уже не влияет на тот факт, будет ли функция заинлайнена на самом деле, даже не inline функции могут быть заинлайнены (при оптимизации -O2 и выше), по крайней мере в gcc так. То есть сейчас спецификатор inline, по-видимому, служит лишь чтобы получить возможность описать функцию в заголовочном файле, и всё. Если я где-то **точно** не прав - прошу поправить, может кто этот вопрос изучал более детально.

Comment: @Alexander Chernin: Абсолютно не верно. Ни о каких "новые имена для вызова одной и той же функции" не может быть и речи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если inline-функция реально была заинлайнена, то её как бы и нету, поэтому она не может дублироваться в принципе.

Если же она не была заинлайнена после оптимизаций, то она получает уникальное имя в каждой единице трансляции, в итоге мы имеем много функций, которые делают одно и то же, но имеют разные имена. Так как имена в итоге разные, multiple definition не происходит.

Подробнее читать здесь: **Стандарт C++11**, 3.2.5 (*One definition rule*), 7.1.2 (*Function specifiers*).

[Где взять стандарт C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417797/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82-c)

Comment: "Если же она не была заинлайнена после оптимизаций, то она получает уникальное имя в каждой единице трансляции". Почему это, если она не была заинлайнена, то получает уникальное имя? Ведь, если "inline" нет, то multiple definition как раз таки происходит.

Comment: Потому что по стандарту если есть спецификатор inline, то на функцию не распространяется "One definition rule", а в противном случае распространяется, я дал ссылки на пункты стандарта, там как раз это и написано. Это значит, что функция, определённая как inline может повторяться, а если нет inline, то она должна линкером быть встречена лишь единожды. Надеюсь моё сумбурное разъяснение вам поможет :)

Comment: Написана грубейшая белиберда. Никакого уникального имени в каждой единице трансляции функция не получает. Вопрос задан о функциях с внешним связыванием, которые гарантированно обязаны иметь один и тот же адрес во всех единицах трансляции. То есть ни о каких множественных копиях с разными именами не может быть и речи.

Answer (score 14):

Если спецификация языка говорит, что ошибки быть не должно, значит ошибки быть не должно. А дальше уже начинаются детали реализации. Почему вы решили, что они не дублируются?

В классической реализации инлайновые функции с внешним связыванием для которых компилятор при компиляции нескольких единиц трансляции решил сгенерировать тела, разумеется, *дублируются*. В процессе компиляции каждая единица трансляции получает свою копию такой функции в своем объектном файле с одним и тем же именем.

Однако такие функции в объектном файле помечены особым образом - так, чтобы при обнаружении множества копий одного и тот же внешнего символа при линковке линкер не выдавал ошибки, а наоборот молча удалял все копии, оставляя только одну. То есть компилятор C++ генерирует "свалку" одинаково именованных функций, раскиданных по разным объектным файлам, а линкер потом собирает всё вместе и занимается чисткой этой "свалки".

В компиляторах семейства *nix эта пометка - это обозначение экспортируемого символа, как т.наз. "слабого" (weak) символа. В компиляторе MSVC++ существует аналогичная пометка `selectany`. Линкеры выдают ошибку множественного определения только если встретят два или более одинаковых "сильных" символа в процессе линковки. Если же "сильный" символ только один (а остальные "слабые"), то побеждает "сильный" символ, а "слабые" символы отбрасываются. Если "сильного" символа нет вообще, а есть только "слабые", то побеждает один (какой-то) из "слабых". Никакой ошибки при этом не рапортуется.

Когда компилятор решает сгенерировать тело для inline-функции с внешним связыванием, он просто помечает соответствующий символ для линкера как "слабый" - и все.

(На этом же механизме построена трансляция шаблонных функций, которые, как известно, тоже определяются в заголовочных файлах и тоже порождают свои копии во всех объектных файлах, которые потребовали их инстанцирования.)

Например, скомпилировав вот такой простой исходник в объектный файл

```
inline void bar() {}

void (*foo())()
{
  return bar;
}
```

и просмотрев содержимое этого объектного файла при помощи `nm` мы [увидим](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93a8b4343bb5e017)

```
0000000000000000 W _Z3barv
0000000000000000 T _Z3foov
```

Буковка `W` помечает "слабый" символ, а буковка `T` - "сильный" символ. Во всех объектных файлах, в которых сгенерировалось тело для такой `inline` функции, она будет фигурировать под одним и тем же именем `_Z3barv` с пометкой `W`.

---

Обратите внимание, что ни о каком решении этой проблемы через генерацию множества функций с *разными* именами не может быть и речи: в всех остальных отношениях инлайновая функция с внешним связыванием должна вести себя так же как и любая другая функция с внешним связыванием, т.е., например, она обязана иметь один и тот же адрес во всех единицах трансляции.

---

Побочным эффектом такого подхода является то, что "классический" подход к формированию объектного файла, в котором у функции нет начала и конца, а есть только точка входа, становится неприемлем. Для того, чтобы иметь возможность исключать функции из объектного файла, С++ компиляторы вынуждены формировать тела функций в объектном файле в компактном виде.

---

Существуют исторические примеры альтернативных реализаций, которые пытались действовать по-другому. "Многопроходные" реализации вообще не порождали тел для инлайновых и шаблонных функций на первом проходе компиляции. Они выполняли предварительную линковку, на которой собирали информацию о том, каким функциям действительно нужны тела, затем снова вызывали компилятор и компилировали уникальные тела для таких функций, и затем уже выполняли финальную линковку. Но среди популярных компиляторов (GCC/Clang/MSVC) такой подход не прижился.

Comment: конечно,  "Когда компилятор решает сгенерировать тело для шаблонной функции с внешним связыванием, он просто помечает соответствующий символ для линкера как "слабый" - и все".  Из за этого  линкерн  просто игнорирует  все коды кроме одного.  Для меня на этом все, но вы обьяснили классно...