# C++, виртуальные методы в шаблонах и наследование

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли в `C++` делать шаблон класса, который имеет виртуальные методы? Особенно, чисто виртуальные:

```
template <typename T, size_t C>
class Template
{
    public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class Impl : public Template<int, 10>
{
    // ...    
};
```

Я попытался провести эксперимент с реализацией, которая смешивает статический и динамический полиморфизм для игровых меню. У меня есть некоторые сомнения в том, что виртуальные методы будут вести себя корректно. Особенно, при наследовании в разных единицах трансляции.

Скажите, что говорит `Стандарт` по этому поводу?

Comment: Ничего не понял. *"возможно ли ..."* Так ведь код компилируется, нет? Значит возможно.

Comment: Код ведь рабочий, просто создаете вутри класса Impl функцию с такой же сигнатурой и пишите override.

Comment: *"имеют подозрительную семантику"* Можно про это поподробнее?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, что будет, если в разных единицах трансляции наследоваться от одного и того же шаблона с одними и теми же параметрами инстанцирования, если в шаблоне реализованы виртуальные методы? Ведь в каждой единице трансляции произойдет инстанцирование одного и того же кода (виртуальных методов). Как компилятор/линкер это разруливает?

Comment: По идее, тот же ворпос можно задать про самые обычные шаблоны, без вирутальных функций. ЕМНИП, действительно инстанцируются в каждой единице трансляции, а линкер потом выбрасывает все копии кроме одной.

Comment: В С++ уже есть синтаксис для указания компилятору того, что шаблон должен быть инстанцирован в определённой точке:  template class (специализация шаблона).    А можно сказать не инстанцировать шаблон в данной единице трансляции:  extern template class  (специализация шаблона)

Comment: @MGNeo: Как компилятор/линкер это разруливает я подробно объяснял здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991757/182825. Ситуация с множественных инстанцированием шаблонов абсолютно ничем не отличается от множественных определений inline-функций и "разруливается" через те же самые механизмы.

Comment: Большое всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблонные методы не могут быть виртуальными. Однако "обычные" методы в шаблонных классах могут быть виртуальными без каких-либо ограничений. То есть никаких особенностей тут нет вообще и почему у вас возник такой вопрос - не ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется. С т. наз. статическим полиморфизмом это довольно перпендикулярно.

Помнится, в STL классы для IO являются шаблонами, при этом вполне себе полиморфными.