# Документация по c++ в gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, книги, документация

Я хочу начать разрабатывать на C++ под пингвином и вопрос у меня следующий. Где найти мануал по c++ я имею введу не учебники каких то левых людей, а **техническую документацию написанную авторами языка и компилятора**, то есть pdf или любой другой формат но именно полная и подробная **ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЯ**. **как к примеру мануалы** по микроархитектурам или что-то в этом вроде. Что начинается не со слов "друзья давайте возьмемся за руки и напишем Hello world!" а со слов " компилятор такой то имеет следующий ряд операторов таких то [подробный перечень как к примеру у ассемблера под разные архитектуры] и т.д.". Просто уже в отчаяние накрывает. где не спрашивал всюду какие то учебники и самоучители пихают в инете нет ничего ну так же не бывает!!! если кто то создал язык он же должен был документацию написать... **МНЕ УЧЕБНИКИ НЕ НУЖНЫ СРАЗУ ГОВОРЮ И САМОУЧИТЕЛИ ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ**

Comment: Это называется стандарт C++, вам он сейчас вряд ли поможет. Берите учебники.

Comment: Еще вот этот вопрос посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/185348.

Comment: И вот этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/185348.

Comment: Товарищи спасибо огромное. Я вас люблю))) вопрос можно считать закрытым огромное спасибо чисто человеческое вы сделали мою жизнь гораздо ГОРАЗДО проще....

Comment: Для gcc [11.1 manuals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/11.1.0/)