# Свой класс exception

Tags: c++, классы, исключения

Я создал свой класс **MyException**

```
class MyException: public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string msg;
public:
    MyException(std::string msg): std::exception(msg)
    {
        
    }
};
```

Пример взят из интернета, но у меня ругается компилятор (gcc) на строчку *std::exception(msg)*

```
note: candidate: 'constexpr std::exception::exception(const std::exception&)'
no matching function for call to 'std::exception::exception(std::__cxx11::string&)'
     MyException(std::string msg): std::exception(msg){
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const std::exception&'
```

После нашел другой пример

```
class MyException: public std::exception
{
private:
    
public:
    MyException(std::string msg);
    ~MyException() = default;
    const char* what() const noexcept override;
};
```

Тут все работает, но у меня есть пару вопросов:

1. Почему я не могу реализовать первый пример, хотя у другого человека получилось? (c++11)
2. Почему в строчке **const char(указатель) what() const noexcept override;** используется последовательность const noexcept override;? Почему я не могу написать просто noexcept override или просто override. Насколько я знаю **noexcept** не позволяет выбросить исключение. И почему используется два раза const? Мы же уже указали, что функция будет константная

Comment: `const` (применительно к методу) используется один раз, `const` и `noexcept` с недавних пор являются частью сигнатуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соседнем ответе объяснили, в чем ошибка. А теперь как чинить.

Да, можно положить в свой класс `std::string` с текстом ошибки, и перегрузить `what()`, чтобы он его возвращал. Но есть нюанс: стандартные исключения можно копировать, гарантированно не получая исключений (например от нехватки памяти) - у них внутри какой-то аналог `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`.

А ваше исключение при копировании сможет выбросить исключение (если `new` кинет исключение) - маловероятно, но все равно не по фен-шую.

Чтобы этого не произошло, можно не хранить строку самому, а унаследоваться от `std::runtime_error` или `std::logic_error`, и хранить строку в нем. Или, если совсем не хочется наследоваться, хранить один из этих классов в своем.

Comment: Например, вот так **err(const std::string& what = "") : std::runtime_error(what) {}**?

Comment: Тогда мне в самом классе при наследовании надо тоже std::runtime_error указывать? или можно оставить std::exception?

Comment: @Barev Надо `std::runtime_error`. В конструкторе после `:` могут быть только родители, нельзя унаследоваться от одного класса а в конструкторе инициализировать другой.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что по стандарту `exception` не имеет конструктора иного, кроме как по умолчанию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что формально ваш код

```
MyException(std::string msg): std::exception(msg)
```

ошибочен. Другое дело, что некоторые компиляторы от стандарта отходят и допускают

```
exception::exception(const string&)
```

Так что по-хорошему, хранить сообщение должны вы сами. Или использовать в качестве родительского иной класс.

Comment: То есть, это зависит от компилятора, например, от VS может допускать данный вариант, а тот же gcc нет?

Comment: Да, я на это когда-то тоже нарывался :)

Comment: Хорошо, с этим я разобрался. А почему я не могу просто использовать сигнатуру **const char* what() const override;** Почему обязан быть noexcept?

Comment: Ну, потому что в стандарте так :)

Comment: Понял! Спасибо!

Comment: А где можно смотреть как выглядит сигнатура этого класса?

Comment: В моем ответе :) Это из стандарта С++20.

Comment: А помимо ответа можно где-то? Если я,например, захочу посмотреть как выглядит в другом классе? :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/195342

Answer (score 1):

1. Наверное вы не внимательно смотрели, или там была опечатка, потому
   что конструктор std::exception не принимает в аргумент std::string,
   а принимает только   С_строку(в некоторых реализациях). Поэтому нужно ему передать именно
   такую строку. Вот, например, так:

   ```
   MyException(std::string msg) 
       : std::exception(msg.c_str())...
   ```
2. спецификатор  `const noexcept override` может быть только для
   функции    члена. Это значит, что функция член определена и для
   константных    объектов (то есть она не изменяет состояние объекта),
   не генерирует    исключение(помощь компилятору) и переопределен в
   производном    классе(то есть это виртуальная функция_член).

А второй констант относится к возвращаемому типу(возвращает указатель на константную строку.

Comment: с char* тоже самое **error: no matching function for call to 'std::exception::exception(char*&)'
 MyException::MyException(char* msg, short code):std::exception(msg)**

Comment: И почему я не могу просто указать **const char* what() const override;**

Comment: Нет, по стандарту у `exception` только один конструктор - по умолчанию.

Comment: @Harry from Kiev, по стандарту нет, но некоторые компиляторы поддерживают

Comment: Тогда к ответу нужно указать компилятор, для которого предназначен этот ответ...